# Understanding result when Mean Value Theorem applied on Antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

When I was going through proof of Antiderivative theorem, I saw following step which comes when we apply Mean Value Theorem on Antiderivative $G$ of $f$.

> $$G(x) - G(a) = G'(t)(x-a) = f(t)(x-a)$$

where $a\leq t \leq x$.

Does this result tells us something intuitive?  Like, We can always express Riemann integration of function (whose Antiderivative exists) in terms of area of one rectangle.

Comment: It's an algebraic representation (and generalisation) of the diagram here: https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/teaching-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-a-historical-reflection-newtons-proof-of-the-ftc

Comment: area of rectangle BβHK = area of curve BβδD ? But how is it happening ?

Comment: In that link Bβ is infinitesimal segment while in our case that is not necessary. Or you are just referencing for diagram ?

Comment: The diagram is valid either way: the IVT says there is a $t$ so that the height of the rectangle is the same as the area of the curve (area is a continuous function of the height, and area of curve is larger than $f(B)$ and smaller than $f(\beta)$, so there is $B<t<\beta$...). The MVT allows you to generalise this to non-monotonic functions.